# Is there a way to provide politicalview in HERE Maps geocoder autocomplete API?

Tags: geocoding, here-api

There are some disputed territories in the world, which are claimed by 2 neighboring countries. E.g. there is a Crimea region, which is disputed between Russia and Ukraine.

To workaround such situations in rendering the map, Here API has a 'politicalview' argument. If it is provided to the API methods, they will return results based on the opinion of a given country. E.g. in the geocoding request, if `politicalview=RUS`, then Crimea will be shown as a Russian region, otherwise it will be shown as Ukraininian.

The problem is that there seems to be no such parameter for the [Geocoder Autocomplete API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/what-is.html). This brings an inconsistency between autocompletion and geocoding.

Since we make apps for Russia, we need to show map with Russian political view. However due to this inconsistency in the APIs we have the following issue:

1. User starts typing some city name in Crimea, like 'Simfero...'
2. Autocomplete Suggestion API provides a suggestion like 'Ukraine, Simferopol'
3. User clicks it without typing the rest
4. We try to geocode that exact string. But with `politicalview=RUS` there is no 'Ukraine, Simferopol', there exists only 'Russian Federation, Simferopol'. So our geocoding yields no result at all, which annoys the user.

So the question is: is there any way to make geocoding and suggestion APIs consistent with the political view?

Answer (score 1):

1. Please migrate to the latest version of the API https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/migration_guide/index.html
2. Currently, there is no `politicalview` parameter available for the Autocomplete endpoint. I guess you should be able to fix most of your problems with some basic text processing (e.g. by replacing "Ukraine" to "Russia" depending on the context).